# Rendering UIView slow performance on iPad 3

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, calayer, ipad-3

I'm using straightforward code to capture the UIView, and it has been working beautifully on the iPad 2 and the original iPad. But it's staggeringly slow on the iPad 3. I know I'm pushing more pixels, but the rendering performance is simply unacceptable.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Please help me in a way to improve the speed of the rendering UIView on the iPad 3.

Thanks.